# Why do conductors moving in Earth's magnetic field not create electricity?

Tags: electromagnetism, geophysics, geomagnetism

if earth is a magnet and there are conductors moving in it why do we not get a current from them, seeing as it is a conductor moving in a magnetic field

Comment: Related: [Can the Earth's magnetic field be used to generate electricity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65082/139130)

Comment: the earth's magnetic field is very weak comparatively

Comment: And something would have to be moving pretty fast to see much change in the magnetic field.

Answer (score 2):

If you refer to conductors standing on the Earth's surface, such as the Eiffel Tower, then it is because these conductors are at rest with respect to Earth's magnetic field.

If you refer to a conductor that is moving, such as all metallic parts of a car, I believe that in fact there are induced currents but they are very small because the magnetic field is very weak.

Comment: "A magnetic field alone doesn't create electricity. A changing magnetic field does." and "The Earth's magnetic field is quite homogeneous over short distances though so the coil would need to move fast and very far to generate much." from Brandon Enright's great answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65082/can-the-earths-magnetic-field-be-used-to-generate-electricity